# qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I was trying to use QEMU with a kernel ISO I am building but I am unable to run the test.

I am using Windows 10 64 bit and I have added the `pc-bios` folder to PATH if that matters.
I have tried the following commands till now:
[Windows terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7EgF.png)

Comment: Similar issue for linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134893/cannot-start-kvm-vm-because-missing-bios

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `bios-256k.bin` that comes with QEMU. Add the following while running your command `... -L "C:\Program Files\qemu"`. Where `"C:\Program Files\qemu"` is the path to QEMU installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I figured it out as well but anyways.

Comment: @Mina Maged Why is this required and when is this required? Is there a command that works for any operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-L C:\Users\Ratul\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\pc-bios\` option to your command line. You tried this option, but used the path and name of the binary, and iIt should contain only the path.